# What is an adequate counter example to disprove that if $A$ is open $f(A)$ is also open?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

What is an adequate counter example to disprove that if $A$ is open $f(A)$ is also open?

$$A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: Consider $A=(-1,1)$ and $f(x)=x^2$

Comment: $\sin(\mathbb R)=[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = 0$. For any non-empty $A \subset \mathbb{R}$,

$$f(A) = \{0\}$$

Which is not open.

$\textit{Edited thanks to clarifying comments.}$

Comment: Closed isn’t the opposite of open (but yes, it isn’t open).

Comment: What if $A = \emptyset$?

Comment: Just because a set is closed does not mean it’s not open

Comment: On the real line, the only closed sets that are also open (aka clopen sets) are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$, so this might seem pedantic, but in more general topological spaces there can be other counterexamples. The property that the empty set and the total space are the only clopen sets called connectedness, and even the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873144/what-is-the-general-outline-of-the-proof-that-the-real-line-is-connected) that the real line is connected isn't a completely trivial consequence of the typical definitions of open and closed sets therein.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If a set is closed on $\mathbb{R}$, it is not open.

Comment: @Roland Almost true, but false.

Comment: Updated the post! Thanks for the corrections!